# L'expression “notre amitié” peut-elle signifier "son amitié" ?

Tags: sens, possessif

Je suis troublé par le changement apparent du tiers à la première personne dans cet extrait:

> C’est même l’un des précurseurs du verlan puisque café vient en fait
>   de « fait cas », par allusion au rituel de courtoisie à l’époque de
>   Louis XIV, qui consistait à recevoir ses amis autour d’un café pour
>   leur témoigner **de notre amitié**, leur « faire cas » en quelque sorte.

Cela veut dire l'amitié de la nation de france vers les amis apparemment pas français ou cela signifie-t-il autre chose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il s'agit de l'amitié des habitants de la France (ou du moins d'une partie de ses habitants, le café étant une denrée fort chère à l'époque) envers les personnes qu'ils recevaient chez eux, toutes les personnes, ce passage ne dit pas qu'il s'agit des étrangers uniquement.

Même si *son* est possible dans cette phrase, l'emploi de *notre* ici ne choque pas, et, à mon avis, est normal. Il renvoie au pluriel que représente *ses amis*. *Votre* aurait aussi été possible.

---

Attention : ce passage est soit humoristique, soit mal renseigné. *Café* vient du turc *kahve* qui lui-même vient de l'arabe *qahwa*. En argot on dit encore un *kawa* (*kahwa*) pour parler du café (la boisson).

Comment: C'est ça. Il y a plusieurs reponse au même question, une de elles etant: 4. "À votre avis, quelle est l’origine du mot Café ?
Pour ce que j’en sais, ce mot est d’origine arabe. D’ailleurs,
avec l’immigration, il est repassé dans sa langue d’origine
puisque mes amis français parlent toujours d’aller « prendre
un kahwa ». On dit d’ailleurs que les meilleurs cafés
sont les purs arabica !"